# extract max value from two column within a group

Tags: r, dplyr

after grouping by `q`, would then like to extract two max value from two different `w` `e` columns respectively

**input data:**

```
q <- c(503,503,503,503,503,503,503,503,503,503,503,503,503,510,510,510,510,510,510,510,510,510,510,510,510,525,526,526)
w <- c(56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56)
e <- c(26,26,26,26,26,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,30,30,30,30,33,33,33)
r <- data.frame(q,w,e, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Code:**

```
r %>% group_by(q) %>% slice(which.max(w & e))
```

**My Output:**

```
  q     w     e
 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  503.   56.   26.
2  510.   56.   28.
3  525.   56.   33.
4  526.   56.   33.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    q   w  e
1  503 56 28
2  510 56 30
3  525 56 33
4  526 56 33
```

would prefer to use `%>%` and `slice` command as the above code instead of finding max separately `q$w` `q$e` and then merging by `q` (would like to avoid `merge` as my actual data is large `object.size` ~2GB)

Answer (score 5):

This is fast `data.table` solution and will scale well to your 2GB dataset.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(r)
dt[, lapply(.SD, max, na.rm=TRUE), by=q ]
```

**Result**

```
    q  w  e
1: 503 56 28
2: 510 56 30
3: 525 56 33
4: 526 56 33
```

**Benchmarking**

```
microbenchmark(data.table = dt[, lapply(.SD, max, na.rm=TRUE), by=q ],
               dplyr1 = r %>% group_by(q) %>% summarise_all(max),
               base = do.call(rbind, by(r, r$q, function(x)
               data.frame(q = unique(x$q), w = max(x$w), e = max(x$e)))), times = 50
)
```

**Result**

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 data.table  810.240 1060.267 1447.979 1192.107 1332.054 14260.901    50
     dplyr1 1562.027 1686.613 1857.382 1759.574 1869.226  3617.279    50
       base 1925.973 2088.107 2448.162 2226.986 2485.760  7395.837    50
```

Clearly `data.table` is fastest.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `slice`, just `summarise_all`

```
r %>% group_by(q) %>% summarise_all(max)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      q     w     e
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   503  56.0  28.0
# 2   510  56.0  30.0
# 3   525  56.0  33.0
# 4   526  56.0  33.0
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than mine; Learning something new everyday so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following `dplyr` code does what you need and also avoid using `merge()`:

```
r %>% 
group_by(q) %>% 
summarize(w=max(w), e=max(e))
```

Returns:

```
      q     w     e
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  503.   56.   28.
2  510.   56.   30.
3  525.   56.   33.
4  526.   56.   33.
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a `tidyverse` solution, but as an alternative, here is a solution in base R using `by`:

```
do.call(rbind, by(r, r$q, function(x)
    data.frame(q = unique(x$q), w = max(x$w), e = max(x$e))))
#      q  w  e
#503 503 56 28
#510 510 56 30
#525 525 56 33
#526 526 56 33
```